# How to create custom annotation in java?

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create custom annotation in java for `DirtyChecking`. Like I want to compare two string values using this annotation and after comparing it will return a `boolean` value.

For instance: I will put `@DirtyCheck("newValue","oldValue")` over properties.

Suppose I made an interface:

```
 public @interface DirtyCheck {
    String newValue();
    String oldValue();
 }
```

**My Questions are**:

1. Where I make a class to create a method for comparison for two string values? I mean, how this annotation notifies that this method I have to call?
2. How to retreive returning values of this method ?

Comment: can you elaborate better what you are after? do you want the compiler to recognize that annotation? or the IDE? or any specific framework that you are using or what?

Comment: As far as I can read from [oracle's website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html), you can't make annotations have methods/functions. They're meant to store metadata value, or data that can identify their purpose.

Comment: I am adding a link speaking of [custom annotation from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-2-098036.html)

Answer (score 22):

First you need to mark if annotation is for class, field or method. Let's say it is for method: so you write this in your annotation definition:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DirtyCheck {
    String newValue();
    String oldValue();
}
```

Next you have to write let's say `DirtyChecker` class which will use reflection to check if method has annotation and do some job for example say if `oldValue` and `newValue` are equal:

```
final class DirtyChecker {

    public boolean process(Object instance) {
        Class<?> clazz = instance.getClass();
        for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(DirtyCheck.class)) {
                DirtyCheck annotation = m.getAnnotation(DirtyCheck.class);
                String newVal = annotation.newValue();
                String oldVal = annotation.oldValue();
                return newVal.equals(oldVal);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cheers,
Michal

Comment: Thanks Michal for your time and answer i have some doubts like
1-Let us suppose i have annotation @DirtyCheck(newValue,OldValue) 
Now i will want to tell my developer to use it so is it possible developer will use only this Annotation syntax in their Set Method and annotation will return me True or False so that developer  know  values are same or not.

Comment: @psisodia I did not catch your idea, could you provide an example?

Comment: Lets suppose I have created an annotation @DirtyCheck(newValue,oldValue) and its class DirtyChecker.java
When I use this annotation in my application like-
@DirtyCheck("hello","hi")
public boolean compare()
{
...mycode...
}
I want to Know how this annotation refers to the method given in my DirtyChecker.java

Comment: `@DirtyCheck` annotation is just a mark. You can mark class,field or method with annotation. And check if object has this annotation in some other code. And accordingly run some actions. Look at [this link](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/java/creating-custom-annotations-and-making-use-of-them/)

Comment: Thanks Michal for your help and support!!
You have written lines "Object has this annotation in some other code. And accordingly run some actions" which helps me to figure out how can I resolve my issue.

Comment: Can it be possible to pass parameter values like that:
                String oldValue1= "test"; 
  String newValue1= "test1";
  
 @DirtyCheck(oldValue = oldValue1,newValue=newValue1)
 public void check2(String myParam) {
   
 }
Note:-oldValue1 & newValue1 are not final variables.
Because in my case I cannot make my values final .I have to pick values from List.

Comment: No annotation attribute has to be constant expression.

Comment: Michal-I want to provide dynamic values to java annotation.can it be possible to pass values to it?

Comment: I think you cannot put dynamic values. Probably the annotations are not the best way to thing you want to achieve.

Comment: @Michal :  How this Reflection based class (DirtyChecker)will be called ? Is there any way it can be called automatically?

Comment: @JyotiYadav i know i am coming 4 years from the future but i could really use the answer to your question, did you find an answer after all ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question: your annotation can't return a value. The class which processes your annotation can do something with your object. This is commonly used for logging for example.
I'm not sure if using an annotation for checking if an object is dirty makes sense except you want to throw an exception in this case or inform some kind of `DirtyHandler`.

For your first question: you could really spent some effort in finding this yourself. There are enough information here on stackoverflow and the web.

Answer (score 2):

**CustomAnnotation.java**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
     int studentAge() default 21;
     String studentName();
     String stuAddress();
     String stuStream() default "CS";
}
```

How to use the field of Annotation in Java?

**TestCustomAnnotation.java**

```
package annotations;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class TestCustomAnnotation {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           new TestCustomAnnotation().testAnnotation();
     }
     @CustomAnnotation(
                studentName="Rajesh",
                stuAddress="Mathura, India"
     )
     public void testAnnotation() {
           try {
                Class<? extends TestCustomAnnotation> cls = this.getClass();
                Method method = cls.getMethod("testAnnotation");

                CustomAnnotation myAnno = method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);

                System.out.println("Name: "+myAnno.studentName());
                System.out.println("Address: "+myAnno.stuAddress());
                System.out.println("Age: "+myAnno.studentAge());
                System.out.println("Stream: "+myAnno.stuStream());

           } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
           }
     }
}
Output:
Name: Rajesh
Address: Mathura, India
Age: 21
Stream: CS
```

[Reference](http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2016/07/create-annotation-in-java.html)