# How to give alias name for the Class in TestNG.xml

Tags: testng

I have testng.xml as below:

```
<classes>
   <class name="com.tecnotree.clm.tests.CorporateHybridRegistrationTest" />
   <class name="com.tecnotree.clm.tests.CorporatePostpaidRegistrationTest" />
</classes>
```

I am getting this class name in `@BeforeClass` and initiating for `extentReport`

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void initializeLog()  throws Exception
    {
        extentLog = extentReport.startTest(this.getClass().getName());
        extentLog.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Started Test Execution for "+this.getClass().getName());

    }
```

I am getting everything proper, now the problem is as the testname is very log, it initiating with same, i want to give my own name.

eg:-Test name comming as `com.tecnotree.clm.tests.CorporatePostpaidRegistrationTest`

Any one, please help how to do that

I want test name like `Corporate Prepaid Registration Test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `com.tecnotree.clm.tests.CorporatePostpaidRegistrationTest` is like that because you asked for it:

> this.getClass().getName()

But you can imagine having another custom logic for a custom name. For example, in a pseudo code:

```
@ExtentReport(name="Corporate Prepaid Registration Test")
public class CorporatePostpaidRegistrationTest {
    [...]

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void initializeLog() throws Exception {
        ExtentReport report = this.getClass().getAnnotation(ExtentReport.class);
        String testName = report != null ? report.name() : this.getClass().getName();
        extentLog = extentReport.startTest(testName);
        extentLog.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Started Test Execution for " + testName);
    }
}
```

Edit: `@ExtentReport` is a custom annotation and doesn't exist somewhere. You have to create it yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am unable to give the annotation `@ExtentReport` before `CorporatePostpaidRegistrationTest`.  Is need to add any jar

Comment: You just have to define it: `@ExtentReport` doesn't exist, it will be your own custom annotation.

Comment: how to define that, can you please help me

Comment: Another subject, another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260037/how-to-create-custom-annotation-in-java